# whereIn query not working laravel

Tags: php, controller, laravel-5

Could you help what's the problem with my query. In the second variable, I can't simply output the thing in my blade it using whereIn method. I'm supposed to add another where in the $filterrecord variable, but upon checking, it's not even going through.

Controller

```
$querys 
    = RecordHistory::select(DB::raw('profile_id, max(effective_date) as date, membership_type'))
        ->groupBy('profile_id')         
        ->orderBy('date', 'desc')
        ->get();

$filterrecord
    = RecordHistory::select('profile_id', 'membership_type')
    ->whereIn('profile_id', $querys)        
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database query returns collection and whereIn accepts array thus first change the collection to an array, you can use the below code and achieve it

```
 $filterrecord
        = RecordHistory::select('profile_id', 'membership_type')
        ->whereIn('profile_id', $querys->toArray())        
        ->get();
```

Comment: This should be working, it's an eloquent method, but it's not.

Comment: What is it giving?

Comment: can you put this dd(DB::getQueryLog()); and see the query and run in phpmyadmin and check if you get data

Comment: after the eloquent query put it and run again

Answer (score 0):

If you use`whereIn` in query then you pass multiple ids by comma separated

```
    $querys 
        = RecordHistory::select(DB::raw('profile_id, max(effective_date) as date, membership_type'))
            ->groupBy('profile_id')         
            ->orderBy('date', 'desc')
            ->get();
    $ids = array(); 
     foreach($querys as $item){
       $ids[]=$item->profile_id;
     }       
    $filterrecord
        = RecordHistory::select('profile_id', 'membership_type')
        ->whereIn('profile_id', $ids)        
        ->get();
```

Comment: Hi, it's giving me this error FatalThrowableError in Grammar.php line 118:
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given, called in /home/vagrant/Code/projects/kjcmis/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php on line 37

Comment: `print_r($ids) do this. It returns an array or not?

Answer (score -1):

Parameter 2th of whereIn is array.But your variable "$querys" is a collection object.convert this to array of list profile_id.

```
$ids = array();
foreach($querys as $item){
  $ids[]=$item->profile_id;
}
```

or

```
$ids = array(); 
foreach($querys as $item){
  $ids[]=$item['profile_id'];
}
```

and use it like:

```
->whereIn('profile_id', $ids)
```